# Out of Memory Error Bitmap With ImageView In Android 4.0 and Above

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I am Getting error on my code : Out of Memory Error

Below is my code :

```
public class ViewFullImage extends Activity {

    //Bitmap bitmap;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView iv;
    private String ImgFile_Name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_draw_picture);

    Log.v("","===================== viewFullImage.java================");

    try{
    String  path = "mfc/cam_img/";


    int s_id=getIntent().getIntExtra("s_id", -1);
    int intentKey=getIntent().getIntExtra("iv", -1);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_display);

    File Dir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File imageDirectory = new File(Dir,path);
    File file  = new File(imageDirectory, "img_"+s_id+"_"+intentKey+".jpg");

    ImgFile_Name = file.getAbsolutePath();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 1;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),options);


    int h = options.outHeight;
    int w = options.outWidth;

    Log.v("","This is h : "+h);
    Log.v("","This is w : "+w);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImgFile_Name,options);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    if(h<w)
    {

        iv.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(bitmap));
    }
    else{
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        Log.v("","Exception : "+e);
    }
    }

    Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 
                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 
                                      matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap=null;

        return bitmap1;
    }
}
```

In this class i am trying to displaying image from sdcard. I am calling this Activity from other activities Like :

```
 Intent intent =new Intent(cxt,ViewFullImage.class);
 intent.putExtra("iv", 8);
 intent.putExtra("s_id", s_id);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Please somebody tell where i m doing mistack.....

Comment: what should i do to display my image ?

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again .... yyy ... i mean have you tried to click the "end of story"?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything wrong, you can't just allocate an image (or even a large string) in Android without knowing if it's going to fit in memory.

The problem happens in Android 4 devices because there is more 4.0 devices out there with only 16MB heaps. The memory heap is the memory where you will open your image in.

To solve this issue you should scale your image if required (depending both on the heap size and image size). Below is the code for how to decode with scaling:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampleImage(File f, int width, int height) {
    try {
        System.gc(); // First of all free some memory

        // Decode image size

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to

        final int requiredWidth = width;
        final int requiredHeight = height;

        // Find the scale value (as a power of 2)

        int sampleScaleSize = 1;

        while (o.outWidth / sampleScaleSize / 2 >= requiredWidth && o.outHeight / sampleScaleSize / 2 >= requiredHeight)
            sampleScaleSize *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = sampleScaleSize;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage()); // We don't want the application to just throw an exception
    }

    return null;
}
```

The other thing is, if you don't free some memory (System.gc()) and you click/switch between many pictures you may run out of memory anyway. If you run out of memory you don't want to blow the app, instead manage the case where the Bitmap is null. You can improve the Exception's catch cases for that as well.

Hope it helps.